# How to display only specific page via router-view?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

can only a specific page be viewed via **router-view**?

**App.vue**

```
<div id="app">
  <div class="out-page" v-if="$route.path === '/login'">
    <router-view name="login"></router-view>
  </div>
  <div class="register-page" v-if="$route.path === '/register'">
    <div class="register-wrapper">
      <router-view name="register"></router-view>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="in-page" v-if="$route.path === '/home'">
    <div class="home-container>
      <router-view name="home"></router-view>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**router.js**

```
export default new Router({
  mode: "history",
  routes: [
    {
      path: "/login",
      name: "login",
      component: () =>
        import(/* webpackChunkName: "Login" */ "./pages/login.vue")
    },
    {
      path: "/register",
      name: "register",
      component: () =>
        import(/* webpackChunkName: "Register" */ "./pages/register.vue")
    },
    {
      path: "/home",
      name: "home",
      component: () =>
        import(/* webpackChunkName: "Home" */ "./pages/home.vue")
    }
  ]
});
```

I need the router-view to enter only content from one particular page, not all of them. The name attribute does not work.

**Is it possible to do this?**

Comment: You should use only one `router-view` element in your template

Comment: I know that, but can it be divided like this or am I unlucky?

Comment: what's your use case and why are proceeding like that?

Comment: There is a different structure and animation on every page, which I only want to do if I put the animation on a particular part, it's more difficult to explain, because I don't speak English well.

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what you are trying to do, but normally, if you have only a single view on the page, the app structure would look more like this:

```
  <div id="app">
    <div class="shared-outer-class">
      <router-view/>
    </div>
  </div>
```

The per view customization would be handled in the individual components themselves, or by some shared outer component if needed.

If you are intending to use [multiple views on same page](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/named-views.html), then you might used named views. But that is not what your example seems to be trying to do.

Comment: Maybe with a bigger adjustment. How do I modify those components on my router when I have them dynamically via () =>?